# JQuery to filter 2 related tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a jquery filter to filter 2 related tables. The rows of each table share an ID, which I am trying to use to tie everything together. The filter works on one table at a time, but then I end up with 1 table filtered and the other not, or depending on my experimenting sometimes all the other rows are gone. Javascript is not my strong suit.

Here is a basic example of the structure:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<table id="table-a">
  <tr>
    <td data-resource-id="1">Adam</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-resource-id="2">Bobby</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-resource-id="3">Charlie</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-b">
  <tr>
    <td data-resource-id="1">Sandler</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-resource-id="2">Knight</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-resource-id="3">Brown</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#table-a tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more i.e : What is excepted output when filtering ?

Comment: @Swati it should only display the rows that correspond to the input, so for example if you type in Adam, it would show that row, but also show the corresponding row from the other table with the last name Sandler.  It works on a single table, I’m just trying to tie the other table to it.

Comment: Hi @RiotAct , you can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qbxnuadg/).

Comment: @Swati sorry its not working. If you are familiar with Fullcalendar.js, this is what I am working with. It is the resource timeline view. Its tough because there are multiple tables going on but the one thing tying these together is the resource id